# Reload carousel items

Tags: sencha-touch, carousel

I need to reload the items from my carousel (I clicked on an item and a panel gets destroyed, then when I try to go back, I need to rebuild the carousel)

For this I am removing the items of the carousel by doing:

```
var len = cards.length;
for(var c = 0; c < len;c++)
this.myCarousel[0].items.remove(cards[0]);
```

then I set the cards again and set the carousel items again:

```
this.myCarousel[0].items.append(cards);
this.doLayout();
```

but after doing this, the cards dont get set right, they just get written on top of each other, no carousel effect gets done. Also the cards start being drawn under the carousel's toolbar, instead of starting below the toolbar.

The first time when I load the cards it works perfectly (when I build the carousel from scratch), but if I delete the previous cards and add them again, they don't get displayed properly, I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I discovered that the problem I was having was caused by something, the view was getting destroyed elsewhere and that is why the carousel wasn't working. But still I am intrigued why I can't call this.myCarousel.removeAll() or this.myCarousel.doLayout();  maybe it is due to fact that I am adding the carousel by doing this.add(this.myCarousel), instead of adding the carousel directly as an item when I create the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the adding and removing on the carousel itself as it has methods to do this:

```
this.myCarousel.removeAll();
var items = [];
for (...) {
   items.push(<item def>);
}
this.myCarousel.add(items);
this.carousel.doLayout(); // Force the carousel to re-render
this.myCarousel.scrollToCard(0); // This will send the user back to the first card
```

If the user was at a different card when you run the above (say, if you put this into an orientation check) then you should return them to the correct card like so:

```
var curIndex = this.myCarousel.items.items.indexOf(this.myCarousel.layout.activeItem);
// Now do removing and adding
this.myCarousel.scrollToCard(this.myCarousel.items.items[curIndex]);
```

You have to use the index as the item will be removed.

Comment: It says that myCarousel does not have any function called removeAll or doLayout. Notice above, that I have to treat myCarousel as an array of objects, but even if I do this.myCarousel[0].doLayout() or removeAll() it says that myCarousel[0] does not have those functions

Comment: Carousel has removeAll and doLayout (check the API ref). Sounds like you don't have a reference to the rendered carousel, just the initial config object. You need to render the carousel and then get that reference. You can do this a number of ways, but you could use an afterender listener to grab the rendered carousel.

Comment: I know carousel should have those functions, but I dont get why I can't call them. The carousel if working fine now. The items.remove(cards[i]) worked after all. But I stil have to call this.myCarousel[0]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have them because you don't have the rendered object just the config object. The config object will have the items (which is why you can do your item manipulation) but won't be instantiated yet as a full object. When you pass it to the rendering functions the carousel object will be created. It's that object that you can use all the proper functions on.

Comment: While this appear to generate new items for the carousel - they do not render.  The "dots" in the carousel reflect the correct number of item but they do not render -- only the initial loading renders.

Answer (score 0):

id should only be used for debugging. There are better ways to resolve a component than use id that can get you into trouble.